# Removing duplicate rows from data frame in R

Tags: r, matrix, reshape, transpose, reshape2

I have two columns, would like to retain only the non commutative rows.For the data below my output should contain one combination of (1 2). i.e. for my query (1 2) is same as (2 1). Is there a simple way to do it in R. Already tried transposing. and retaining the upper traingular matrix. but it becomes a pain re transposing back the data.

```
A B prob
1 2 0.1
1 3 0.2
1 4 0.3
2 1 0.3
2 3 0.1
2 4 0.4
```

My final output should be:

```
A B prob
1 2 0.1
1 3 0.2
1 4 0.3
2 3 0.1
2 4 0.4
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want, but my first thought was to remove just all rows where `B` is smaller than `A`.

Comment: unfortunately in my actual problem columns a and b are not numbers, they are product codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by the `pmin(A, B)` and `pmax(A,B)`, `if` the number of rows is greater than 1, we get the first row or `else` return the rows.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, if(.N >1) head(.SD, 1) else .SD ,.(A=pmin(A, B), B= pmax(A, B))]
 #   A B prob
 #1: 1 2  0.1
 #2: 1 3  0.2
 #3: 1 4  0.3
 #4: 2 3  0.1
 #5: 2 4  0.4
```

---

Or we can just used `duplicated` on the `pmax`, `pmin` output to return a logical index and subset the data based on that.

```
 setDT(df1)[!duplicated(cbind(pmax(A, B), pmin(A, B)))]
 #   A B prob
 #1: 1 2  0.1
 #2: 1 3  0.2
 #3: 1 4  0.3
 #4: 2 3  0.1
 #5: 2 4  0.4
```

Answer (score 7):

We can independently [`sort()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sort.html) each row and then use `!`[`duplicated()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html) to find which rows to preserve:

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df[1:2],1L,sort))),];
##   A B prob
## 1 1 2  0.1
## 2 1 3  0.2
## 3 1 4  0.3
## 5 2 3  0.1
## 6 2 4  0.4
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L),B=c(2L,3L,4L,1L,3L,4L),prob=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.1,0.4
));
```

---

## Explanation

The first step is to extract just the two columns of interest:

```
df[1:2];
##   A B
## 1 1 2
## 2 1 3
## 3 1 4
## 4 2 1
## 5 2 3
## 6 2 4
```

Then we independently sort each row with [`apply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) and `sort()`:

```
apply(df[1:2],1L,sort);
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2
## [2,]    2    3    4    2    3    4
```

As you can see, `apply()` returns its results in an unexpected transposition, so we have to fix it with [`t()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html) to prepare for the upcoming `duplicated()` call:

```
t(apply(df[1:2],1L,sort));
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    2
## [2,]    1    3
## [3,]    1    4
## [4,]    1    2
## [5,]    2    3
## [6,]    2    4
```

Now we can use `duplicated()` to get a logical vector indicating which rows are duplicates of previous rows:

```
duplicated(t(apply(df[1:2],1L,sort)));
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

We then invert the logical vector with a negation, to get just those rows that are *not* duplicates of any previous rows:

```
!duplicated(t(apply(df[1:2],1L,sort)));
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Finally we can use the resulting logical vector to index out just those rows of `df` that are not duplicates of any previous rows:

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df[1:2],1L,sort))),];
##   A B prob
## 1 1 2  0.1
## 2 1 3  0.2
## 3 1 4  0.3
## 5 2 3  0.1
## 6 2 4  0.4
```

Therefore, the *first* occurrence of every set of post-sort duplicates will be retained, the remainder will be removed.

---

Excellent suggestion from @RichardScriven; we can replace the `t()` call with the `MARGIN` argument of `duplicated()`, which will likely be slightly faster:

```
df[!duplicated(apply(df[1:2],1L,sort),MARGIN=2L),];
##   A B prob
## 1 1 2  0.1
## 2 1 3  0.2
## 3 1 4  0.3
## 5 2 3  0.1
## 6 2 4  0.4
```

Comment: it has worked , thanks a lot , can you please also explain what is happening at the backend. Which occurence will it retain 1 2 one or 2 1 , i would want to retain the 1 2 one.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. Basically the script of bgoldst works in the backend in the same way. Except of the `paste` part. Only the FIRST occurence will be returned.

Comment: You actually don't need to transpose.  You can do `duplicated(apply(df[-3], 1, sort), MARGIN = 2)` to check duplication over the columns.  But either way works.

Comment: Woah, Thanks a lot Florian for the detailed explanation. I wonder when was the last time I had this much clear context of the backend of R. And thanks bgoldst for this awesome snippet. Richard you saved a little more code.Thanks to you too. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
d <- data.frame(A=rep(1:2, each=4), B=rep(1:4, 2), p=rnorm(n=8))
> d
  A B           p
1 1 1 -1.26282557
2 1 2 -0.03627707
3 1 3  1.50063527
4 1 4 -0.30038114
5 2 1 -0.01509190
6 2 2  0.13634069
7 2 3 -0.39612927
8 2 4 -0.10895007
l <- 1:nrow(d) # Create an index vector
v <- apply(cbind(d$A, d$B), 1, sort) # Make (1, 2) look like (2, 1)
v <- paste(v[1,], v[2,]) # Create vector where (1, 2) and (2, 1) both look like '1 2'
fun <- function(x) return(x[1]) # Function for tapply to only return the first match for the pattern
i <- tapply(l, v, fun) # get relevant index
res <- d[i, ] # Create result vektor
> res
  A B          p
1 1 1 -0.6742351
2 1 2 -1.5895396
3 1 3 -1.5975784
4 1 4 -1.4764792
6 2 2 -0.1682946
7 2 3 -0.5799141
8 2 4  2.4104019
```

Be aware that this will use the FIRST occurence of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using base R. The idea is to search in the second half of the `df` (using `sapply`) if there are any duplicated there. We then get back `secondHalf` vector. We further remove those rows from `df`.

```
n <- nrow(df)
secondHalf <- sapply(seq(n/2), function(i) nrow(df[df$A==df[i,2] & df$B==df[i,1],]))
# [1] 1 0 0
toRemove <- ((floor(n/2)+1):n)*secondHalf
df <- df[-toRemove,]

  # A B prob
# 1 1 2  0.1
# 2 1 3  0.2
# 3 1 4  0.3
# 5 2 3  0.1
# 6 2 4  0.4
```